# Replacing each character/string in a list one at a time with python

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a string "MQADKVMEPT" and the desired output I want is:

```
.QADKVMEPT  
M.ADKVMEPT  
MQ.DKVMEPT  
MQA.KVMEPT  
MQAD.VMEPT  
MQADK.MEPT  
MQADKV.EPT  
MQADKVM.PT  
MQADKVME.T  
MQADKVMEP.
```

Using this code:

```
motif = 'MQADKVMEPT'
motiflist = list(motif)

pos = 0
for aa in motiflist:
    motiflist[pos] = '.'
    pos += 1
    str = ''
    for a in motiflist:
        str += a
    print(str)
```

My output is:

```
.QADKVMEPT
..ADKVMEPT
...DKVMEPT
....KVMEPT
.....VMEPT
......MEPT
.......EPT
........PT
.........T
..........
```

How do I reinitialize the original motiflist so that it doesn't give me this output?

Answer (score 0):

"Quick" fix would be copy the original list. Using your code:

```py
motif = "MQADKVMEPT"
motiflist = list(motif)

pos = 0
for aa in motiflist:
    motiflist_copy = motiflist.copy()  # <--- copy the original list
    motiflist_copy[pos] = "."
    pos += 1
    s = ""
    for a in motiflist_copy:
        s += a
    print(s)
```

Prints:

```
.QADKVMEPT
M.ADKVMEPT
MQ.DKVMEPT
MQA.KVMEPT
MQAD.VMEPT
MQADK.MEPT
MQADKV.EPT
MQADKVM.PT
MQADKVME.T
MQADKVMEP.
```

---

Shorter solution:

```py
motif = "MQADKVMEPT"

for i in range(len(motif)):
    s = motif[:i] + "." + motif[i + 1 :]
    print(s)
```

Comment: I'd say moving `motiflist = list(motif)` into the loop would be even quicker.